# Push notification when available but keeping 2.0 compatibility

Tags: iphone

The new IPhone OS 3 enabled push notifications, which I'd like to use, however, this would be the only feature of 3.0 that I would be interested in. I noticed that the TapTap Revenge application kept their 2.0 compatibility in the store, yet when I upgraded my device to 3.0, I got the popup to enable the notifications. Does anyone know how they managed that? I considered compiling for 2.0 and checking if the UIApplication responds to the registerForRemoteNotificationTypes selector, and calling it if so.

Answer (score 2):

See [how-do-you-optionally-use-iphone-os-3-0-features-in-a-2-0-compatible-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986589/how-do-you-optionally-use-iphone-os-3-0-features-in-a-2-0-compatible-app)

Answer (score 1):

Over in the dev forums on apples site ([devforums.apple.com](http://devforums.apple.com)) in the 3.0 area there is talk about how to do this.

I don't have the bookmarked link in front of me, but once I dig it up off my other computer I'll edit this post.

This jist of it is.

- Set Base SDK to the SDK with the features you want to use (in this case 3.0 for push)
- Set the target platform in the project options to the lowest OS version you want to support (for my app I'll pick 2.2.1)
- Check programitaclly for the existance of the features you want to use so you can degrade gracefully when the program is run on an older version of the OS (prime example - and one I am going to use using in my app - is push notifications).

Hope that helps.

chris.