# Can you build an iPhone app which has 2.1 as it's target SDK, but uses 3.0 features?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I noticed that IM+ came out today and lists it's minimum requirements (in iTunes) as OS 2.2 or later, but they support 3.0 features like push.

Is it possible to build an app (eg: one binary) for firmware 2.1 that has features like push (or SMS or whatever) that are only enabled on phones with the 3.0 firmware? It seems like it is, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986589/how-do-you-optionally-use-iphone-os-3-0-features-in-a-2-0-compatible-app).