# Build iPhone app for 2.2.1 but use 3.0 features (copy & paste)

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to add copy and paste to my application but make it available to 2.2.1 devices. How should I proceed?

I saw *[SDKs and Deployment Targets](http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/06/23/sdks-and-deployment-targets/)*.

If I understand correctly, I set the base SDK to 3.0 in order to be able to compile with 3.0 API (copy & paste), but I set the target for 2.2.1 to make the application available on 2.2.1 devices. In my code, I have to check every time I need to use a 3.0 API, right? Is there an example of code for testing if an object respond to a specific message? If a specific kind of class exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986589/how-do-you-optionally-use-iphone-os-3-0-features-in-a-2-0-compatible-app) which includes a pointer to [Apple's MailComposer example](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MailComposer/index.html)...