# Designing for iPhone OS 2.0 and 3? Is that possible?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an application built for iPhone 2.0 but I would like to use StoreKIT to offer in-app purchase.

If I recompile the code under 3.0, I can use StoreKIT but I will piss those who bought my app and do not upgraded to 3.0.

Is that a way to create a code that can work on both worlds? If yes, what steps should I follow?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986589/how-do-you-optionally-use-iphone-os-3-0-features-in-a-2-0-compatible-app/1025580) about how to use 3.0-only features in a 2.0 compatible app.  The sample code is for using the mail compose controller, but you should be able to do this with the store kit framework too.