# Debug for iOS 3.x in xcode with SDK 4.1

Tags: xcode, ios

I've downloaded the latest SDK from developer.apple.com and can only pick 3.2 or 4.1 from *Project > Properties > Base SDK*.

My iPhone is 4.1

My client have iPhone 3.x

You feel the problem...

How can I debug for iOS 3.x in xcode with the 4.1 SDK installed?

Comment: After a few minutes of research I have come to the conclusion that I can't simulate 3.x on the xcode simulator when I have a newer SDK. I have to buy the physical device. If something isn't correct in my statement, please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible have I come to understand.

You have to buy a old iPhone 3.x.

If you want my opinion on this, then I think this is horrible, frustrating and completely *not* understandable.

Comment: Think about it: can you, for example, make a Windows Vista behave exactly like a Windows XP ? Of course not, so why do you expect that from iOS ?

Comment: you can save the various simulators/sdks as they come out for future problems such as this, but unless you have a copy of the 3.x sdk laying around on a seperate drive or something you are out of luck im afraid.

Comment: You can grab them from here: http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/old-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html

Answer (score 3):

Actually that's a [very frequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358033/iphone-base-vs-active-vs-deployment-target) (was lazy, only linked one).

Short version: you need to set your Base SDK to the highest SDK version you've got and your project's **Deployment Target** to the lowest version you like to support, e.g. 3.0. This means, the Deployment Target specifies the oldest version your app should be able to run on. But beware, this setting does not prevent you from accidentially calling, say, methods available since 4.0 on an 3.0 iPhone and thus causing a method missing exception.

Comment: I understand that, DarkDust. But for example, when my client runt the application a few labels isn't visible on his device, but it is on mine. On my device everything is fine, but on his, it isn't. How can I simulate 3.x on my device so I can fix the problems?

Comment: @FernandoRedondo Do you something like having your 4.x device behave as if it was a 3.x device ? Only by downgrading :-) Seriously, there is no other way. There might be a way to make simulator run an older version, though, but I don't know how to do that (except for the versions it supports out of the box).