# Using Base SDK iOS 6.0.2 in Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode

I've installed Xcode 4.6 beta (which includes iOS 6.1 beta SDK) but do not wish to install iOS 6.1 on my (development) iPhone quite yet. What I'd rather do is continue developing with iOS 6.0.2 (or use the iPhone simulator instead).

Hence I've tried to download and install iOS 6.0.2 into XCode 4.6: indeed in its Organizer window both iOS 6.1 (by default) and iOS 6.0.2 (by this action) now do show up. However when I try to change the base SDK for my project (under its Build Settings) Xcode still seems unaware of the second choice: The only iOS-related choices available are iOS 6.1 and Latest iOS (i.e. again iOS 6.1).

How do I add (the installed) iOS 6.0.2 SDK to that list so I can select it as base SDK for my project?

P.S. My current understanding that this is different from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856807/debug-for-ios-3-x-in-xcode-with-sdk-4-1) other (frequent) question.

P.S.S. Presumably nothing of this is specific to Xcode 4.6 as opposed earlier versions. Therefore I feel authorized to mention it even outside the confidentiality agreement, for its existence as such is clearly publicly known.

Comment: If you want a Base SDK of 6.0 instead of 6.1, use Xcode 4.5, not 4.6. Why use a beta version of Xcode if you are not using the corresponding beta iOS SDK?

Comment: Isn't Xcode 4.6 still under NDA?  If so discuss this on https://devforums.apple.com

Comment: @rmaddy Because another development iPhone (which I do not use right now) has iOS 6.1 beta installed, hence I upgraded to Xcode 4.6 beta as well. I do not want to downgrade/reinstall XCode 4.5 (and it should not be necessary).

Comment: @trajanfoe My P.S. mentions why I think it's permissible to mention Xcode 4.6 here. My question applies more generally to use of XCode n (which comes with iOS m) together with iOS (m - 1). I'm only mentioning specific version numbers in order to make the problem sound concrete (which it is).

Comment: You need to have both versions of Xcode installed.  Use each where appropriate.

Comment: how did you get the ios 6.0.2 sdk? i'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @MohamedHafez if memory serves, I downloaded it from the [iOS Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action#downloads) at the time. Maybe it is no longer separately available, since iOS 6.1 has been released by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set target to lower version !

[image: Set target]

Comment: Yep, that was it: I had originally confused base SDK (e.g. iOS 6.1) and development target (e.g. iOS 6.0).