# supporting iPhone 2.2.1

Tags: iphone

I wonder how many users still have not upgraded their phones from version 2.2.1. I'm asking because my iphone application still supports it! Does it make sense to support 2.2.1 when 3.1 is out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is good to support as wide a selection of devices as possible because it's a bigger potential user base. What is more, for iPod Touch users it is not a free upgrade from 2.x to 3.x, which can be a put-off for them to upgrade. From observations I still see about 20% of my user base running OS 2.2.1 or earlier.

If you find features in later versions of the OS that you'd like to leverage and still keep backwards compatibility as an option, [there are techniques for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986589/how-do-you-optionally-use-iphone-os-3-0-features-in-a-2-0-compatible-app).