# Fallback on older API versions to allow limited functionality on older OS versions

Tags: iphone

I am considering to use a function that was introduced in an iPhone OS version (say 4.0), but I may still want to support devices with older versions and just disable that function.

What would be the best practice for doing this? Is it even allowed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you optionally use iPhone OS 3.0 features in a 2.0 compatible app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986589/how-do-you-optionally-use-iphone-os-3-0-features-in-a-2-0-compatible-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `respondsToSelector`. The related/dup question points to an Apple example, that's a good indication that Apple allows it.

I voted my question a duplicate. Thanks!