# iPhone SDK4.0 with OS3.0

Tags: ios4

I upgraded to SDK4.0 - but the lowest OS supported is 3.2 (which is iPad). How could I compile code for OS3.0 with SDK4.0 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Support legacy iPhone users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088624/support-legacy-iphone-users)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer:

[Support legacy iPhone users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088624/support-legacy-iphone-users/3122653#3122653)

Summarizing, set the Base SDK to 4.0 and the Deployment target to 3.0.  And don't ask who taught English to the engineers at Apple :-)