# What iPhone OS to target?

Tags: iphone

I'm building several different projects for iPhone (and iPod Touch, I suppose) in XCode. What is a reasonable iPhone OS target deployment version?

For instance, can 2nd generation iPod Touch devices upgrade to iPhone OS 3, so that I could be using iOS3 as reasonable minimum and still target the iPod Touch (figuring it's OK to ignore those who don't want to update their OS)?

Part of this question, I suppose, is what is the market share of the different iPhone OS versions among deployed Apple devices (iPhone/ iPod Touch/ iPad)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too localized, because any answers provided will only apply to the current state of installed OSs and devices.  This changes on an almost daily basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old iPhones and iPod Touches should be able to run 3.1.3 (but note that Apple charges for upgrades). iPads only run 3.2 at the moment.

Of course you miss the real question: **Will users on OS 2.x buy my app?**

There's no easy way to tell without phoning home on a new install (and even that's not entirely indicative), but I suspect the answer is no.

Comment: ... I mean, Apple has previously charged for some iPod Touch upgrades. iPhone upgrades have always been free.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021929/what-percentage-of-iphone-users-have-the-different-versions-of-iphone-os-firmware

and this:

[Support legacy iPhone users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088624/support-legacy-iphone-users)