# iOS Legacy Support, is it worthwhile?

Tags: iphone

I need to add a method to an app I am writing that only works on iOS 4 (and above), there is a way I can do it that works on anything above iOS 2 but Apple says that the use of this older method is discouraged in iPhone OS 4.0 and later. My question is if I go with the newer iOS 4 method will I be severely limiting the user base of the app. I would assume that most folks have upgraded to iOS 4, but I really have no idea on the numbers involved. I am just curious as to what others think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Support legacy iPhone users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088624/support-legacy-iphone-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my 2c: I think most people will upgrade because it is so easy to do so I wouldn't bother caring about lower versions of iOS4 - but that just my opinion.

Comment: Hi Anders, I was thinking along the same lines, especially as the 3G and 3GS will both run iOS4. Much appreciated.

Comment: You are wrong: there are people "stuck" with iOS 3 that cannot upgrade - original iPhone and iPod Touch, that's 5-10 Million devices

Comment: from the POV of doing for enterprise it seems iOS 4 is the WTG due to the iPad. Similar to that nobody really develops for WinXP nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a perfectly good function that works for iOS 3, I say use it, deprecated or not. Wait until you create an app that actually needs new functionality from iOS 4 before you shut out the older devices.

I don't know what the ratio of 3.0 devices to 4.0 devices is, but I wouldn't be surprised to find out there are still quite a few 3.0 devices out there. I always target 3.1, and I plan to continue to do so for at least another year.

Comment: ++: between 5 to 10% stuck on iOS 3 as of last qtr, from what i recollect from question on Quora

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Anders K on the basis of opinon (hence +1) - however it may be useful to keep in mind that iOS4 on a 3g or 3gs iphone is really slow and I know many people who dislike iOS4 and I'm sure there are even more who won't want to upgrade because of the issues.

Plus if you want to transfer to iPad (the current version) it will be difficult if you use features only available in iOS4 and above.

All that said - I wouldn't bother, personally. Its easy enough for people to upgrade.

Comment: Yes iOS 4 is really slow especially on 3G. Personnally, I have an 3G iphone and I keep stuck to iOS3. I will migrate to iOS 4 when I will buy a new iphone.